# Take relative file path as CLI input in a Node program

Tags: node.js, filesystems, command-line-interface

In a CLI app, I need to take in a relative path to a file, and pass an absolute path to `fs.readFile`. How can I accept the relative path as input but convert it to an absolute path, even if the Node script is being run from a different directory than it is in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `path.resolve` with `process.cwd()` and the input file.

When you have a path relative to the JS file you are running, you usually use `path.resolve` with `__dirname`. However, in the case where the user supplies a path as a CLI argument, they may be running the JS file from a different directory. To get the directory they are running the script from, you can use `process.cwd()` (Current Working Directory).

```
$ node some-folder/index.js ./myFile.txt
```

```javascript
const { resolve } = require("node:path")
const { argv, cwd } = require("node:process")
// or with ESM
import { resolve } from "node:path"
import { argv, cwd } from "node:process"

const relativePath = argv[2] // input file
const absolutePath = resolve(cwd(), relativePath)
// absolutePath looks like /.../myFile.txt, but if we 
// used __dirname instead of cwd(), it would be 
// /.../some-folder/myFile.txt, relative to the JS file 
// instead of where the file was ran from

// now you can use absolutePath with fs.readFile or etc
```